# Google sheet inventory quantity

Tags: javascript

I have an inventory spreadsheet "Inventory" that has 3 sheets. Inventory List, Parts Used, On Order. And has a form to submit what parts were used to the Parts Used sheet. There is also another spreadsheet "Parts Received" that has a form to submit data when parts are received.

I am trying to

Reference the Part Number from the Parts Used sheet "column E" (each time a form is submitted) to the Inventory List sheet part number "column D". And Subtract the quantity on the Parts Used sheet "column H" from the Inventory List sheet quantity "column H".

So each time the parts used form is submitted to the parts used sheet, it deducts that quantity from the Inventory list sheet, using the part number as a reference to know what two quantities to subtract.
I have tried getting this code to work but with no luck

```
function updateInventoryFromPartsUsed() {
    var partsused = {}; // A mapping of partNumber => quantity.
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Parts Used');
    if (sheet) {
        // For each row, if column "E" == "stock" then set partNumber, quantity.
        partsused[partNumber] = quantity;
    }
    // Now partsused should look like {'SL249':5, 'ML50':1, 'MWF':1}
    sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Inventory');
    if (sheet) {
        // For each row, set quantity, partNumber.
        var purchased = purchaseOrders[partNumber];
        // Set column "A" value = quantity + purchased
    }
}
```

Have also tried different formulas such as: 1. VLOOKUP(B23,$A$2:$B$5, 2, TRUE) to compare data. This did not work either

I am having problems with this. If someone could help I would really appreciate it

Thanks

Bryan

**Someone else has solved this** (will post the answer here, if it might help any one):

By adding two more columns to the right of H 'Inventory List' - Adding these:

I3 =arrayformula(if(row(A3:A)=3,"Parts Used",if(len(D3:D),sumif('Parts Used '!E6:E8,D3:D,'Parts Used '!H6:H),)))

J3 =arrayformula(if(row(A3:A)=3,"Parts Remaining",if(len(D3:D),H3:H-I3:I,)))

They also did this. Added a condition format to 'parts used'

A3:K34 is =isna(match($E3,indirect("Inventory List!D3:D"),0))*len($E3)

This will highlight a row on 'Parts Used' when a part number does not match one on the 'Inventory List'. Helps you see if someone entered a part number incorrectly or if the part needs added to the inventory list.

The solution they gave worked great, very helpful.

Thanks for taking the time to read the question

Comment: What is the value that is returned, what is the value that you expect. Post toy/actual data so it's reproducible.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13WOgd-UrreGuus4Gbf78Jnq1-fqwBX3R_qOd2rZf2mw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: No value is returned. The value that I expected is what I explained in the original question. The part number from 'Parts Used' to reference the 'Inventory List' part number and subtract the their quantities.

Comment: Please edit all this into the question

Comment: Kind of a lot to upack here: 1)How do I loop through an array to find a value 2)How do I read/write data to google sheets using code 3)How do I trigger code to execute on form submission. Why don't you break up your question into manageable chunks. To answer this question is to write an entire small program for you.

Comment: I understand what you mean